# How to sum item from a dictionaries in python 3

Tags: python-3.x

How to sum item from a dictionaries in python 3? I want to add `income` in the dictionary below

```
list [[{'age': 22, 'income': 20.00, 'sex': 'male'}], 
      [{'age': 32, 'income': 50.00, 'sex': 'male'}]]
```

I like to add income 20.00 + 50.00.

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell what you want. Can you add an example of what you tried, and tell what is going wrong?

Comment: I like to add income 20.00 + 50.00.

Comment: I'd say, read a few tutorials on Python, it will be a more effective way to learn Python. Ask a question on SO if you get stuck while you're writing a program. Generally here you're expected to already have some code you can run.

Answer (score 0):

```
incomeSum=0
for entry in list.iteritems():
    incomeSum+=entry["income"]
```

Some quick rough code that should work

Answer (score 0):

The more *pythonic* way is

```
sum(x[0]['income'] for x in list)
```

Also, you don't need to wrap those dicts in a list.

Anyway have a look at a few tutorials, like here in the Python docs: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html